# Is there a link between residues of a function and the branches of its Reimann surface?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm still learning complex analysis and one time, I watched a video of Reimann Surfaces, so I'm not expert in any of these ideas.

Nonetheless, I was experimenting with contour integral over the complex plane. I learned that if a function is not holomorphic, it is not as simple as finding the antiderivative and then plugging in the values.

One function I experimented with is $\frac{1}{z}$. It's integral on the unit circle is $2\pi i$. I saw that if I just calculated the integral, and evaluated the logarithms on different branches, the answer is the same, i.e.:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z} = \ln|a|-\ln|a| + n2\pi i = n2\pi i = 2 \pi i$$

when $n=1$ and for some $a \in \gamma$

However, for another non-holomorphic function:

$$\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z^2} = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a} = 0$$

because there aren't any branches.

Another example is:

$$\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}} = \pm 2(\sqrt{a} \pm \sqrt{a})$$

let $a=1$, and if we choose the correct branches, we see $-4$ is indeed a solution.

So my question is, is the integral over a line in the complex plane as simple as finding the antiderivative, then taking into account the branches of the antiderivative?

Comment: It is **Riemann,** not Reimann! – [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann)

Comment: My vocabulary is not that rich in complex analysis. What I meant is that the method I used to solve *some* integrals I've written above worked, and I'm willing to see if that's just a coincidence or not.